# How to append images to a div that is contained in a map marker infowindow (leaflet)

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I have a list of images where the src gets fetched from the database. For each one in the list it creates an image and append it to a div. However, my div is represented in a string that has the code that is supposed to appear on each marker that I have, I think that's the problem. Is there any way to solve this problem? Here what I have so far:

```
 $.each(data, function (i, item) {

            var aux

            item.listaOcorrencias.forEach(function (ocorrencia, o) {

                aux = ocorrencia.fotografia;

                $(aux).each(function () {

                    $('#myDiv').append('<img src="imagensFogos/' + this.fotografia + '" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow" style="width:70px; height:60px" hspace="4"/>')
                });


                //Here is the infowindow that contains myDiv

                var infowindow = '<div id="content" style="hight:700px; width:500px">' +
                    '<div id="siteNotice">' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div id="bodyContent">' +
                    '<p><b>Avaliação da Ocorrência:</b></p>' +
                    //Here is where the images should be appended
                    '<div id="myDiv" class="flex-parent" style="display:flex}"> </div>'


                    '<div class="button-holder">' +
                    '<a href="#slider-image-1" class="slider-change"></a>' +
                    '<a href="#slider-image-2" class="slider-change"></a>' +
                    '<a href="#slider-image-3" class="slider-change"></a>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div> ' +
                    '<p id="estadoP"> Estado: ' + item.estado + '</p>' +
                    '<button id="aceite" onclick="aceite()" style="background-color:#4CAF50;border: none;color: white;padding: 5px 12px;text-align: center;display: inline-block;font-size: 16px; box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19); margin:5px;">Aceitar</button>' +
                    '<button id="recusado" onclick="recusado()" style="background-color:#f44336;border: none;color: white;padding: 5px 12px;text-align: center;display: inline-block;font-size: 16px; box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);margin:5px;" >Recusar</button>' +
                    '<button id="concluido" onclick="concluido()" style="background-color:#008CBA;border: none;color: white;padding: 5px 12px;text-align: center;display: inline-block;font-size: 16px; box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);margin:5px;" > Concluído</button>' +
                    '</div>';

                //definição do icon para o marcador
                var ignicao;

                var marker = new L.marker([item.latitude, item.longitude], { icon: ignicao })
                    .bindPopup(infowindow)
                    .on('click', onClick)
                    .addTo(map);


           //adds marker to map

                $('#json map').append(marker);


            });


        }); 
    });
```

Comment: `'<div id="myDiv" class="flex-parent" style="display:flex}"> </div>'` has two typos -- `style="display:flex;"` and you do not concatenate the string after this one... does it work if you change that line of code to `'<div id="myDiv" class="flex-parent" style="display:flex;"> </div>' + `.  You should find a way to separate your content/scripts/styles better. It would make it much easier to read/maintain.

Comment: I don't think there is another way of doing this infowindow, I think it needs to be in a string, I was hoping someone could help me with that